# Präpositionalgruppe - ja oder nein? Korrekte Zeichensetzung?

Tags: grammar-identification

Ziel der Frage ist es, die korrekte Zeichensetzung beurteilen zu können. Dafür möchte ich das Satzkonstrukt genauer entschlüsseln. Um folgenden Satz geht es:

> *Als letzter Schritt* **vor dem Beginn des Projektes** musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.

Ist es korrekt, dass hier keine Kommata stehen oder dürfen/müssen hier welche gesetzt werden?

Auffällig finde ich die Austauschbarkeit des kursiven und fettgedruckten Teils. In dieser Version funktioniert es für mich nicht mehr ohne Kommata:

> Vor dem Beginn des Projektes, als letzter Schritt, musste ein Prozess
>   gewählt werden.

Jeder Teil könnte einzeln könnte auch weggelassen werden und der Satz wäre trotzdem noch korrekt.

Handelt es sich um eine, bzw. zwei Präpositionalgruppen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es handelt sich um einen Passivsatz, und zwar um einen Vorgangspassiv.

- **ein Prozess**
  Grammatisch ist diese Nominalgruppe das Subjekt, semantisch das Patiens.
  Weil das Subjekt kein Agens (Täter) sondern ein Patiens (ein »Erdulder«) ist, handelt es sich um einen Passivsatz. Weil es sich um das Subjekt handelt, steht die Nominalgruppe im Nominativ.

  Häufig steht das Subjekt an Position 1, der Satz würde dann so aussehen:

  > Ein Prozess musste als letzter Schritt vor dem Beginn des Projektes gewählt werden.
- **musste gewählt werden**
  Diese Wörter bilden zusammen das Prädikat im engeren Sinn. (Das Prädikat im weiteren Sinn enthält auch noch alle anderen Bestandteile des Satzes mit Ausnahme des Subjekts.) Alle Verben müssen am Ende des Satzes stehen, davon wird aber immer genau 1 Verb nach vor, an die Position 2 gezogen. Wenn es (so wie hier) ein Modalverb gibt, wird das Modalverb vorgezogen. Wenn es kein Modalverb, aber ein Hilfsverb gibt, wird dieses vorgezogen. Wenn es nur ein Vollverb gibt, wandert dieses Vollverb an Position 2 (in diesem Fall verbleibt kein Verb am Ende des Satzes). Das vorgezogene Verb ist das finite Verb.

  - *musste* - Modalverb
  - *gewählt* - Vollverb
  - *werden* - Hilfsverb
- **als letzter Schritt vor dem Beginn des Projektes**
  (Ich nenne diesen Satzteil *»**P1**«*)
  P1 ist eine Präpositionalgruppe, die zum Prädikat im weiteren Sinn gehört und das Prädikat im engeren Sinn ergänzt bzw. näher beschreibt. P1 beantwortet die Frage *»Wie musste ein Prozess gewählt werden?«*
  Dass P1 ein einzelnes Satzglied ist (dass es sich bei diesen 8 Wörtern also nicht um 2 oder mehr Satzglieder handelt) erkennt man auch daran, dass in deutschen Aussagesätzen das finite Verb (bis auf ganz wenige Ausnahmen) immer an Position 2 stehen muss (das finite Verb ist jenes Verb, das von seiner "ursprünglichen" Position am Satzende nach vor gezogen werden muss, siehe oben). Alles vor dem finiten Verb ist also **1** zusammenhängendes Satzglied.

Aber P1 besteht aus zwei Teilen:

- **als letzter Schritt** (*»**P2**«*)
  Das ist auch eine Präpositionalgruppe, allerdings eine etwas kürzere. Auch P2 würde als Ergänzung des Prädikats funktionieren, und wenn man P1 durch P2 ersetzt, würde man einen vollständigen und völlig korrekten deutschen Satz erhalten:

  > Als letzter Schritt musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.
- **vor dem Beginn des Projektes** (*»**P3**«*)
  Auch das ist eine Präpositionalgruppe, und auch sie könnte man anstelle der ursprünglichen langen Gruppe verwenden:

  > Vor dem Beginn des Projektes musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.

  Allerdings würde P3 in diesem neuen Satz das Prädikat näher beschreiben, so wie das auch P1 und P2 tun. Das ist in dem zu analysierenden Satz aber nicht der Fall. In dem zu analysierenden Satz fungiert P3 als Attribut von P2. P3 beschreibt im ursprünglichen nicht wie bzw. wann gewählt werden musste. P3 beschreibt stattdessen, wann der letzte Schritt stattfindet.

Attributiv verwendete Präpositionalgruppen kommen im Deutschen aber nur als Postpositionen vor, das heißt, sie werden dem Bezugswort bzw. der Bezugswortgruppe nachgestellt.

Weil es sich bei P3 um ein Attribut von P2 handelt, darf dazwischen kein Komma gesetzt werden. Weil P1 ein Präpositionalobjekt des Prädikats ist, darf auch nach P1 kein Komma stehen.

---

Wie sieht es aus, wenn man die Positionen von P2 und P3 vertauscht? Dann erhalten wir das:

> Vor dem Beginn des Projektes, als letzter Schritt, musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.

Ich behalte die bisherigen Bezeichnungen P2 (*»als ...«*) und P3 (*»vor ...«*) bei.

Das was jetzt vor dem finiten Verb *»musste«* steht, ist wieder ein einzelnes Satzglied. Es ist aber keine Präpositionalgruppe, sondern eine Aufzählung. Denn sowohl P2 als auch P3 beziehen sich hier auf das Prädikat und nicht aufeinander. Daher kann man das Komma auch durch das Wort *»und«* ersetzen:

> Vor dem Beginn des Projektes und als letzter Schritt musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.

Bei Aufzählungen muss man die einzelnen Teile der Aufzählung immer durch Kommas voneinander trennen. Lediglich das letzte Komma sollte man durch ein Bindewort (meist *»und«*) ersetzen:

> Marmor, Stein und Eisen bricht.

Das ist aber nicht zwingend:

> Rosen, Tulpen, Nelken
>   alle drei verwelken

---

Eine weitere Möglichkeit, den Satz mit den vertauschten Satzteilen zu verstehen, ist diese Interpretation:

> Vor dem Beginn des Projektes, sozusagen als letzter Schritt, musste ein Prozess gewählt werden.

Statt *»sozusagen«* könnte man auch die Adverbien *»quasi, gleichermaßen, gleichsam«* und *»gewissermaßen«* verwenden. Diese Adverbien leiten Gleichnisse ein. Das ganze Gleichnis (egal ob mit vorangestelltem Adverb oder ohne) funktioniert dem Prinzip nach auf semantischer Ebene wie ein Attribut, das heißt es beschreibt das was davor steht näher, grammatikalisch ist es aber eben keine Präpositionalgruppe, denn wenn das Adjektiv vorhanden ist, ist das erste Wort der Gruppe eben keine Präposition sondern ein Adverb. Daher muss diese Gruppe mit Kommas abgetrennt werden. Warum diese Kommas auch dann notwendig sind, wenn das Adverb fehlt, ist zugegebenermaßen etwas schwerer zu argumentieren, aber man kann sich hier mit einem Null-Adjektiv behelfen. Man postuliert also die Existenz eines unsichtbaren Adjektivs welches das Gleichnis einleitet.

Comment: Wow, danke für die sehr ausführliche und gute Antwort :)

Answer (score 3):

Es handelt sich um zwei Präpositionalgruppen, wobei die zweite das Nomen der ersten erläutert: der Schritt kam zeitlich vor dem Projekt. Und zwischen der PP und dem Bezugswort steht kein Komma. (Daß die Struktur so und nicht anders ist, erkennt man daran, daß anderenfalls das Vorfeld von zwei Konstituenten besetzt wäre, was normalerweise vermieden wird.)

Die umgekehrte Reihenfolge funktioniert nicht, weil das Bezugswort immer *vor* der PP stehen muß; die Bedeutung würde sich also ändern zu "das Projekt als Schritt", was hier nicht gemeint ist. (Vergleiche: "Das Projekt als ein Schritt zur Entspannung der Beziehungen zwischen den Parteien war ein Erfolg, obwohl die technischen Vorgaben nicht erreicht wurden.")

Wollte man die Reihenfolge dennoch umkehren, müßte man also anzeigen, daß keine der beiden PP sich auf die andere bezieht, d.h. beide sich auf die Hauptaussage (das finite Verb) beziehen. Das ist wie erwähnt normalerweise nicht erlaubt, weil das Vorfeld nur eine Konstituente fassen kann. Daher muß man anzeigen, daß die normale Grobstruktur des Satzes durch einen Einschub ("als letzter Schritt") erweitert wird, und Einschübe dieser Art werden durch Intonation bzw. durch Kommata besonders markiert.